# Reshape and rename Pandas DataFrame column axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
    Date        Col1      Col2
0   2000-01-01  Val 1a    Val 2a 
1   2000-01-02  Val 1b    Val 2b
2   2000-01-03  Val 1c    Val 2c
3   2000-01-04  Val 1d    Val 2d
```

I need to reshape it, as well as give a name to the column axis so that is looks like this:

```
Column_Name     Col1      Col2
Date        
2000-01-01      Val 1a    Val 2a 
2000-01-02      Val 1b    Val 2b
2000-01-03      Val 1c    Val 2c
2000-01-04      Val 1d    Val 2d
```

According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html#reshaping), I'm guessing what I need is something inbetween `pivot()` and `stack()`, but I can't seem to figure it out exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Using [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) functions from Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df.set_index('Date').rename_axis(columns='Column_name')
```

Result:

```
Column_name    Col1    Col2
Date                       
2000-01-01   Val 1a  Val 2a
2000-01-02   Val 1b  Val 2b
2000-01-03   Val 1c  Val 2c
2000-01-04   Val 1d  Val 2d
```